# Asking for teaching recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

I'm a postdoc and have recently taught/designed a graduate-level course. Who would be the best person to ask for a teaching recommendation?

I was thinking of our associate chair, who oversees course approvals and assignments. I want to include the syllabus, class project description, an example of homework, my teaching evaluation, sample video of my teaching from one of the lectures.

I would appreciate any input on what to attach and what to ask, should I ask for their emphasis that I also designed the course, or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The associate chair would be good in this case, but ask them, or a representative they select to observe you in the classroom, possibly several times.

Along with a recommendation, they can also provide you with feedback and advice on how to improve your teaching. I suspect most new instructors will benefit from that and it is part of the evaluation process in some places.

And an observation or three can lead to a more "personal" recommendation.